# How do I replace an Int property with an Enum in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity class that has a property with an underlying db column of datatype Int, however in reality I want this property to be an Enum. Is there any way to specify that this property returns an Enum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indirectly, like [so](http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/archive/2008/09/18/enum-in-ado-net-entity-framework-v1.aspx).

Personally, I leave the storage int public (for example as `DbFoo`, where the enum property is `Foo`) - that way I can still write lambdas against the column for execution at the DB, for example:

```
where row.DbFoo == SomeConstant
```

If you don't expose the storage value, you can't do this as cleanly. You could equally leave it internal, and have some methods in the context to do the filtering... here's one I wrote earlier today:

```
public IOrderedQueryable<User> Administrators
{
    get { return Users.Where(x => x.DbUserType == User.UserTypeAdmin)
             .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

where `User.UserTypeAdmin` is my internal constant. In this case, I couldn't use a discriminated subclass, as it was interfering with ADO.NET Data Services.

Comment: I use the same method, and it works great. That is until EFF supports enums by default...