# How can this Linq2Sql create an enum in the select clause?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, enums, enumeration

i've got the following linq2sql query, and i'm setting the result to a POCO. One of my POCO properties is an enumeration.

```
public IQueryable<Models.Achievement> GetAchievements()
{
    return from a in _sqlDatabase.Achievements
        select new Models.Achievement
            {
                // Note: ToEnum is an extension method that converts an int -> the enum.
                AchievementType = a.AchievementTypeId.ToEnum<Models.AchievementType>(),
                DateTimeCreated = a.DateTimeCreated,
                UserId = a.UserId
            };
}
```

When i run the query, i get the following error.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Method 'Models.AchievementType 
    ToEnum[AchievementType](int)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

hmm. is there a way i can be tricky enough to make the result int get converted to my custom enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use enums directly in LINQ-to-SQL (but not Entity Framework); just change the type of the property (in the dbml/designer) to the fully qualified enum type, and it will do the cast for you. You might want to call it AchievementType, of course - and this assumes a straight (cast) translation.

If this doesn't fit your scenario, you'll probably have to select it as an integer, and then do the final cast in LINQ-to-Objects (via AsEnumerable()). You could also try a straight cast (assuming this is sufficient) instead of your generic extension method:

```
select new {..., AchievementType = (AchievementType) foo.Bar, ...}
```

Not that if the `Models.Achievement` type is defined in the dbml, you can't create it this way - you have to simple select it. But if this is not part of the db-model then it is fine. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211875/linq-to-sql-mapping-enum-from-string#211894)'s a related example for mapping strings to enums in LINQ-to-SQL.

If neither of these suits, the other approach is to declare the enum property as a shim in a partial class. I gave an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353190/how-do-i-replace-an-int-property-with-an-enum-in-entity-framework#353195) (for EF, but it works the same), but note that if you do this, you can't use the enum property in `Where` clauses etc, since it isn't mapped in the model.

Comment: Wow - awesome! i removed my AchievementType L2S class and renamed the AchievementTypeId field to AchivementType. Then set the property type to my FQDN enum struct. MS tested -> worked! awesome! not only does it work, but my designer is cleaner with the lookup classes now removed! awesomesauce!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this in you Models.Achievement declaration:

```
  AchievementType achievementType{
    get
      {
         return this.AchievementTypeId.ToEnum<Models.AchievementType>();
      }
      set
      {
        this.AchievementTypeId = (int)value;
      }
    }
```